# How to use QLPreviewController in a non-modal way? Why does my code not work?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have `QLPreviewController` up and running but I'm using `PresentModalViewController()` to show the `QLPreviewController` directly. For reasons beyond explanation, I would like to have my own `UIViewController` which will create its own view and within that view I would like to use the `QLPreviewController`. Should be easy I thought, but the code below just does nothing. The QLPreviewControllers `ViewDidAppear` never gets called. (In my example below, PreviewController inherits from `QLPreviewController` and encapsulates delegate, preview item and source).
Can somebody explain what is wrong with the code below (besides the fact that it is pointless :-))?
Oh, yeah: in my test scenario, I present the controller below modally. It shows up but witout the preview.

```
 public class OuterPreviewController : UIViewController
        {
            public OuterPreviewController (QLPreviewControllerDataSource oDataSource) : base()
            {
                this.oDataSource = oDataSource;
            }

            private PreviewController oPreviewController;
            private QLPreviewControllerDataSource oDataSource;

            public override void LoadView ()
            {
                this.View = new UIView();
                this.View.Frame = new  RectangleF(0, 0, 500, 500);
                this.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;

            }

            public override void ViewDidAppear (bool animated)
            {
  // Code execution comes her. No errors, no issues.            
  base.ViewDidAppear (animated);
                this.oPreviewController = new PreviewController();
                this.oPreviewController.DataSource = this.oDataSource;
// Preview controller's view is added but it never shows up.                
this.View.AddSubview(this.oPreviewController.View);
                this.oPreviewController.View.Frame = this.View.Frame;
                this.oPreviewController.View.Center = this.View.Center;
            }

            public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution by coincidence today: all `ReloadData()` on the preview controller and magically it will show its contents.

This allows to add a `QLPreviewController` to an existing view as a subview and embed a preview. It also gets you rid of the toolbar which contains the **open in** menu.

Comment: Hey there Krumelur , I am trying to do just the same (open OuterPreviewController into a subview) , I see your solution regarding the reloadData thing but I can't see a way to implement it, can you kindly give me directions to that? thanks.

Comment: Hm, I can't quite remember but I just had to call ReloadData() on the QLPreviewController once everything was initialized.